# CSS rem strange behaviour

Tags: css

I have an issue with CSS rem font-size. Here is my code (check on [codepen](https://codepen.io/fox_hover/pen/6bed07200be757c0a91e43901d53de4b)):

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.57rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>Rem Test</h1>
```

Rem definition tells that h1 font-size must be between 35px and 36px, but it's actual font-size is 41.2px. And for 36px I must put 2.3rem Could you please help me with this issue? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `rem` (root `em`) goes from the root element, which is `<html>`

See the following:

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.57rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>Rem Test</h1>
```

There is also a pseudo element called `:root` which you could use instead (should work in any major browser)

Comment: You're welcome :) instead of `html` you can use `:root` as well